# Plotnine : Secondary y-axis (dual axes)

Tags: python, plotnine

I am using python's wonderful plotnine package.  I would like to make a plot with dual y-axis, let's say Celsius on the left axis and Fahrenheit on the right.

I have installed the latest version of plotnine, v0.10.1.

[This](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/68) says the feature was added in v0.10.0.

I tried to follow the syntax on how one might do this in R's ggplot (replacing 'dot' notation with underscores) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month':('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'),
    'temperature':(26.0,25.8,23.9,20.3,16.7,14.1,13.5,15.0,17.3,19.7,22.0,24.2),
})
df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'], categories=('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'), ordered=True)

p = (ggplot(df, aes(x='month', y='temperature'))
  + theme_light()
  + geom_line(group=1)
  + scale_y_continuous(
        name='Celsius',
        sec_axis=sec_axis(trans=~.*1.8+32, name='Fahrenheit')
  )
)
p
```

This didn't like the specification of the transformation, so I tried a few different options.  Removing this altogether produces the error:

```
NameError: name 'sec_axis' is not defined
```

The [documentation](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) does not contain a reference for `sec_axis`, and searching for 'secondary axis' doesn't help either.

How do you implement a secondary axis in plotnine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/68) github issue thread that was mentioned in the question does not say in any way that the secondary axis feature has been implemented. It was added to [v0.10.0 milestones list](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/milestone/1) before it was released. Here, milestones list means a todo list of what was planned to be implemented before the version releases. However, upon the actual release, the [changelog](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html) does not mention the secondary axis feature, which means that it was only **planned** to be implemented and was **not actually** implemented. Long story short, the planned feature didn't make it into development and release.

So, I'm sorry to say that currently as of v0.10.0 and now v0.10.1 it seems that this feature isn't there yet in plotnine.

Comment: Oh, snap!  Sad news indeed as I have been wanting this feature for ages and thought it was finally here.  Hopefully it is included in the next release as I really do think it's valuable.